# Mass-Assignment Roles issue in controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, tdd

I'm developing an application using Devise.
Since I need a UI to manage users I also generated a controller and associated views to perform all CRUD operations on the User model.

Then I create a "role" field that I use with CanCan and as a mass-assignment role.

Now I'm trying to make all specs properly, I have this test

```
describe "POST create" do
  describe "with valid params" do
    it "creates a new User" do
      expect {
        post :create, {:user => valid_attributes}
      }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end
    # ...
  end
end
```

That when executed raises:

```
UsersController POST create with valid params creates a new User
Failure/Error: post :create, {:user => valid_attributes}
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
   Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name, surname, role
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:62:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:61:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

And where my controller's #create method is defined as
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      load_and_authorize_resource

```
  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  # GET /users/new.json
  def new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new params[:user], :as => current_user.role.to_sym
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Utente creato con successo.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
     if @user.update_attributes(params[:user], :as => current_user.role.to_sym)
       format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Profilo aggiornato con successo.' }
       format.json { head :no_content }
      else
       format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

To make rspec run properly with Devise I followed [the official doc](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29) and I also created macros (the same as described there), except I don't have two different FactoryGirl but one where I define on creation the role, for example:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:user, role: :admin) # or role: :user
```

And this is the User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name, :surname, :role, :as => :admin

  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,
         :validatable

  VALID_ROLES = [:admin, :student]

  validates_inclusion_of :role, in: VALID_ROLES

  def is_admin?
    role == "admin"
  end

  def is_student?
    role == "student"
  end
end
```

How can I fix that? It took all my day and I couldn't get this working :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by cancan's `load_and_authorize_resource` that is calling `User.create` without allowing me to declare the ":as" clause containing the role.

The fix was actually to remove the call to `load_and_authorize_resource` and create the resource in a typical way (as you would do without cancan). Then call in each method the authorization check, that is `authorize! :create, User` for #create.

Probably it would also work by using something like `load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:create]` and then do it manually only there, but I'm not sure and I didn't test it.

By the way I've lost a working day on this bug and I really hope this can help someone else having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since Rails version 3.2 there has been a security implemented.
To fix your error add the following line to your User model:

```
attr_accessible :name, :surname, :role
```

For more details read this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Comment: Hi, sorry. I forgot to put the User model on the OP. I've edited it now. I know I have to declare attr_accessible and that's where I get the issue... I am trying to use mass-assignment roles.

Answer (score 0):

You got the user in de 'post' line wrong. Change this:

```
post :create, {:user => valid_attributes}
```

to this:

```
post :create, :user => {valid_attributes}
```

I assumed your variable 'valid_attributes' is a hash with the attributes for that class.